# Querying SQL IN for list of strings

Tags: sql

I have the following query which returns 0 results which I know is wrong. However not sure what is off with my syntax.

```
select * from SJT_USER where SJT_USER_NAME in
    ( select USER_NAME from NON_MEMBER);
```

`SJT_USER_NAME` type `NCHAR(255 CHAR)`

`USER_NAME` type `NVARCHAR2(255 CHAR)`

I'm guessing I need to do some conversion from NVARCHAR2 to NCHAR.

Comment: Both answers so far probably solve your issue but if this is more than a one-off you should consider using a foreign key and joining the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try a SQL Cast so you're comparing apples to apples. I'm not certain which DBMS you're using, but the syntax should be similar to this:

```
select * from SJT_USER where SJT_USER_NAME in ( select CAST(USER_NAME AS NVARCHAR2) from NON_MEMBER);
```

Answer (score 0):

A CHAR or NCHAR is fixed length so it the SJT_USER_NAME is padded by spaces so it fills up the 255 chars. When comparing the two there are two options. You can either TRIM or use RPAD:

```
select * from SJT_USER where TRIM(SJT_USER_NAME) in ( select USER_NAME from NON_MEMBER);
```

or

```
select * from SJT_USER where TRIM(SJT_USER_NAME) in ( select RPAD(USER_NAME,255) from NON_MEMBER);
```

The later might be preferable if you have an index SJT_USER_NAME. IF performance is not concern I usually prefer to have a TRIM on both sides of the comparison just to be on the safe side.